# Dual display resolution issue in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I've got a 1980x1020 monitor connected to a 1366x768 laptop running Windows 10. Everything was okay but today I turned the laptop on without turning on the monitor (it wasn't powered), and turned the monitor on half an hour later. My settings (extend displays) were reset to mirror displays. When I switched to extend displays I found out that I can only choose between 800x600, 1280x600 and 1280x720 for my Full HD monitor. How can I force Windows 10 to choose the correct resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that was too easy. I disconnected the monitor and reconnected it. Looks like Windows recognized it as some other monitor for some reason (and even rebooting couldn't change it).